# Eigen Matrix referencing specific sections of an Eigen Vector

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I have a stack of 6x1 vectors as an `Eigen::VectorXd`. Suppose each vector is composed by the entries `xi = [Kx, Ky, Ky, Lx, Ly, Lz]`. If my stack is composed by 3 vectors then it will look like :

```
xi_stack [K0x, K0y, K0y, L0x, L0y, L0z,
          K1x, K1y, K1y, L1x, L1y, L1z,
          K2x, K2y, K2y, L2x, L2y, L2z]
```

I then need an `Eigen::MatrixXd` to store the skew symmetric operator for every K vector;
In other words, the matrix should look like this:

```
K_hat_stack = 

  0  -K0z  K0y
 K0z   0  -K0x
-K0y  K0x   0
  0  -K1z  K1y
 K1z   0  -K1x
-K1y  K1x   0
  0  -K2z  K2y
 K2z   0  -K2x
-K2y  K2x   0
```

I would like to reduce copies as much as possible so I would like this matrix to directly reference the correct section of the stack vector; i.e., once the stack is computed, the `Eigen::Matrix` is automatically available with the correct data and can be used to further matrix multiplications.

I tried using `Eigen::Ref` or accessing the pointed with `.data()` function.

I was expecting to being able to manually set the pointed data in order to have an ad-oc filled matrix.

Comment: There is no way to doing this without changing the `xi_stack` unless you want to [implement your own operator](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html) for doing this on-the-fly. Speaking of the stack, what exactly is it? How is it different from a 6x3 matrix?

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that!

For the stack, basically I have a 6x1 which has to be computed at several points.
Each `xi` is obtained via a matrix mapping : `Phi` x `q`. Where `Phi` is a 6xn matrix and `q` is a nx1 vector. 

As I need to computed it for several points, the most efficient way is to stack all the matrices `Phi` into a big one (these are constants and never change). Multiplying this stack with `q` gives me the stack of `xi` in a very efficient way.